# About the definition of a curve in topological space

Tags: general-topology

I was wonder about the definition of a curve in topological (maybe normed space, so that one can do calculus on) space $X$:

$\hspace{4cm}$ A curve $C$ is a continuous function $\gamma: I = [0, 1] \rightarrow X$

My questions are:

1. Why it has to be the unit interval $I$?
2. Why not some closed, connected (but might not compact) set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so that the curve, still remain connected, could, in some sense, go to $\infty$?
3. And what about a set $S$ in general?

I looked up continuous functions that map disconnected set to connected set for the 3rd question, but there was not any info about them.

Comment: Math is all about exploration. Think about all of the theorems about curves you know. Which of them would hold for a more general set $S$? Which of them only make sense if the domain is a closed interval $[0,1]$? Math is discovered by humans who make (sometimes arbitrary) definitions and explore the consequences of those definitions. Be a part of that process and explore for yourself!

Comment: The best answer to this is the users comment above.